# Games for 2 players on same laptop?

Tags: games

I only have 1 laptop, and want to play with another person.
No joystick/mouse/anything.
What games can I use?

As per [meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/6184/on-topic-what-games-can-be-played-by-two-people-on-the-same-computer): Don't add a new answer, but edit the Community Wiki answer.

Requirements:

- Fun with two players
- Enjoyable without spending an hour learning the rules
- Free, open source is ideal
- Usable offline, no flash-based nor online-based games.
- Link to Ubuntu package appreciated
- two-players-at-one-keyboard or hotseat or anything else OK

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Racing

Bump Race - bumprace package

Super Tux Racer - supertux-stable package

SuperTuxKart

Armagetron http://armagetronad.org

## Worms-like

Hedge Wars - hedgewars package

Warmux - warmux package

Slingshot

## RPG

Battle for Wesnoth http://www.wesnoth.org/

Lordsawar - lordsawar package

Wings 2 http://www.wings2.net

## Tetris-like

Block Attack - blockattack package

## Platform games

JVGS (http://jvgs.sourceforge.net/) - not in repository

Fish Fillets (http://fillets.sourceforge.net/) - in repository

## Sport

Neverputt

## Emulators

- Super Nintendo - zsnes package
- Nintendo DS - desmumepackage
- Nintendo 64 - mupen64plus package
- Nintendo Wii - xwiimote package
- PlayStation - pcsxr package
- Atari 2600 - stella package