# Game for two players on one PC

Tags: games

I search a (non online) game for two players on one laptop.

The game should be simple since my son has the mental age of a five year old child.

It would be nice if the game could be controlled by two game controllers.

I imagine something like a jump and run game or something like boulder dash.

Update: 2D is preferred to 3D games.

Comment: See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/260528/games-for-2-players-on-same-laptop

Answer (score 0):

Some of my friends like [SuperTuxKart](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/FAQ#What_is_SuperTuxKart):

> SuperTuxKart is a Free 3d kart racing game; we want to make the game fun more than we want to make it realistic. You can play with up to 4 friends on one PC, racing against each other or just try to beat the computer (a network multiplayer feature is under development).

I haven't played it myself, and my friends are twenty-year-olds. It should support multiple controllers (or at least with a workaround: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1667997).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I get headache from 3D games. I prefer 2D.

Comment: @guettli It's not the needs-glasses-type 3D (that causes headaches, right?)